# Why is this push() overwriting instead of adding?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a line of code inside a http callable Firebase Function that is supposed to add a new record to a spot in the Firebase Database.

`return admin.database().ref('games/' + gameid + '/' + uid + '/logs/').push().set({guess: guess, result: pigs.toString() + 'P ' + bulls.toString() + 'B', score: score});`

Here is an example entry in my database.

```
"games" : {
    "39dba69c-f5a8-4e94-9553-d19372d43a92" : {
      "1P0mWbp1jYOayaMEyQcnKvX4YB63" : {
        "logs" : {
          "-LDshYx2wJK6eT47_OVQ" : {
            "guess" : "5647",
            "result" : "1P 1B",
            "score" : 450
          }
        },
        "maxbulls" : 3,
        "maxpigs" : 3,
        "moves" : 6,
        "score" : 450
      },
      "answer" : "2739dba69c41",
      "id" : "39dba69c-f5a8-4e94-9553-d19372d43a92",
      "requestor" : "1P0mWbp1jYOayaMEyQcnKvX4YB63",
      "status" : "pending",
      "turn" : ""
    }
  }
```

For some reason the `set()` is overwriting the record under logs (id of -LDshYx2wJK6eT47_OVQ). I want it to add a new record under logs with the auto-generated key from `push()`. I have used a very similar method before (with basically no differences) that worked as intended.

I have also tried changing `set()` to `update()` but it still overwrote. Is there something wrong with my path or database structure that I am overlooking? Thanks.

Comment: That seems *very* surprising. Calling push on `/games/39dba69c-f5a8-4e94-9553-d19372d43a92/1P0mWbp1jYOayaMEyQcnKvX4YB63/logs` should add a new child node, not overwrite existing child nodes. I'm not sure what could be causing that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I call one other update on the game path before this call, without using a `then()`. It doesn't touch the log path though. That shouldn't cause it?

Comment: That's hard to say without seeing the actual code and how it interacts. The best way to allow us to help is to reproduce the problem in isolation.  Have a look at [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).